# MaterialUI Table rows with different amount of cells aligned

Tags: material-ui

I am trying to create a table where I essentially have two headings of different cell size and the items in the table must follow the second heading, like this:

```
       **Main Heading 1**         |         **Main Heading 2**
sub 11 | sub 12 | sub 13 | sub 14 | sub 21 | sub 22 | sub 23 | sub 24 
item   | item   | item   | item   | item   | item   | item   | item
...
```

I have tried with the following structure

```
<Table size="small" aria-label="stock-flow">
<TableHead>
    <TableRow>
    <TableCell>Main Heading 1</TableCell>
    <TableCell>Main Heading 2</TableCell>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
    <TableCell>Sub 11</TableCell>
    <TableCell>Sub 12</TableCell>
    <TableCell>Sub 13</TableCell>
    <TableCell>Sub 14</TableCell>
    <TableCell>Sub 21</TableCell>
    <TableCell>Sub 22</TableCell>
    <TableCell>Sub 23</TableCell>
    <TableCell>Sub 24</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
</TableHead>
<TableBody>
    <TableRow>
    <TableCell>Item 11</TableCell>
    <TableCell>Item 12</TableCell>
    <TableCell>Item 13</TableCell>
    <TableCell>Item 14</TableCell>
    <TableCell>Item 21</TableCell>
    <TableCell>Item 22</TableCell>
    <TableCell>Item 23</TableCell>
    <TableCell>Item 24</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
</TableBody>
</Table>
```

But that aligns **Main heading 1** and **Main Heading 2** above `sub11` and `sub12` and leaves 6 empty spaces after that.

I essentially want to have 2 "main" columns and a way to create whatever sizes of columns/rows I want in each of them.

**EDIT:** I found the answer, I have to use the `colSpan` property and give it a value of the amount of cells that I want to have underneath the main heading, so both headings get `colSpan={4}`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I have to use the `colSpan` property and give it a value of the amount of cells that I want to have underneath the main heading, so both headings get `colSpan={4}`